# Увеличить объем обрабатываемых файлов на сервере node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

цикл на сервере node js, перестает перебирать JSON файл,

```
server.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '1024mb', parameterLimit: 10000000,extended: true }))
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '2048mb',parameterLimit: 10000000, extended: true }))
```

Пытался сделать через лимиты, но они тоже не помогают, или же лимиты слишком малы, что делать с этим делом??

```
server.post("/save", (req, res) => {
    const mapsStorage = path.join(publicPath, 'maps');
    const createDirName = req.query.locname;
    const dir = path.join(mapsStorage, createDirName);

    const map = req.body;
    
    !fs.existsSync(dir) && fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    !fs.existsSync(path.join(dir,"assets")) && fs.mkdirSync(path.join(dir,"assets"));
    fs.writeFileSync(dir+"/map.json", JSON.stringify(map));
    for(let piece in map){
        if(piece !== "locSize"){
            map[piece].map(item=>{
                let imageName = item.texture.match(/([a-z]+\/){3}(.+\.png)/i)[2];
                if(!fs.existsSync(path.join(dir,`assets/${imageName}`))){
                    console.log(path.join(dir,`assets/${imageName}`));
                    fs.copyFileSync(path.join(publicPath,item.texture), path.join(dir,`assets/${imageName}`));
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: эмм, а у тебя при "копировании игровой карты" реально прилетает с клиента 2Гб инструкций?

Comment: я написал большое число, чтобы проверить, реально ли проблема в лимитах

Comment: у меня минимальная карта 5000х5000 пикселей, ландшафтный блок занимает 60х60, при сохранении карты мне нужно сохранить все картинки, которые использовались в рисовании этой карты, но копируется всего одна картинка, а ведь помимо ландашфта есть всякие объекты по типу деревьев, камней, грибочков

Comment: странно. ты пишешь "цикл на сервере nodejs, перестает перебирать JSON файл", но не пишешь ничего об ошибке. ошибки нет? а как тогда ты "понял", что цикл остановился? может ты так решил из-за того, что ты не написал никакого возврата клиенту `res.json({ ok: 1 })` - цикл отработал и ... всё?

Comment: ошибок нет, у меня объект вида {size:{}, landscape:[],gameObjects:[]}, но перебирается только landscape(size я скипаю)

Comment: Я нашел проблему вообщем